# Backbone & Require - Destroy view when navigating away

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I've read [Derick Bailey's article on Zombies](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) but can't seem to figure it out. I have a backbone application that uses require.js and need to be able to close/destroy a view when I navigate away from it.

There's a lot of ways to initiate a backbone app, but what is the right way when using require to allow for clean up?
And how can I call a **close()** function on views just before navigating away?

**Main.js**

```
require([ "app", "backbone", "router", "facebook"], function(App, Backbone, Router, FB) {

    //theres a lot of facebook integration
    FB.init({
        appId      : '********',
        version    : 'v2.0'
    });

    //force the page to go to index when first arriving
    window.location.hash = "";

    new App;

    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

**App.js**

```
define([ "backbone", "router" ], function(Backbone, Router){

var App = function () {
    Router;
}

return App;
})
```

**Router.js**

```
define([ "backbone", "models/user" ], function(Backbone, User){

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
               //All my routes
           },
            index: function () {
                require([ "views/index", "models/user" ], function (IndexView, UserModel) {
                    var indexView = new IndexView({ model: UserModel });
                 })
            },

           // Remaining route functions

return new AppRouter;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

That post solves a problem that your code here doesn't have.

The problem (zombie views) only occurs when your views have attached event handlers to a model instance.

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  setup: {
    // model instance will now be storing a callback which is bound 
    // to *this* instance of a view
    this.model.on('change', this.render, this); 
  },
  render: function () {
    // whatever code that uses the context, `this`
    this.$el.innerHTML(this.model.get('title'));
  }
});
```

Then in your app lifetime, the above view got rendered and then the page changed, or whatever happened, and the view is not needed anymore. But there might anything else that is using the model that this view has used – and that model might keep changing and then it will fire a callback for `change` event, the `render` method which will point at seemingly non-existent view.

But since that view might not have its element in the DOM anymore, you'll get DOM errors (if for example your render method referenced `this.$el.parent()`) and the views will remain in memory without you knowing it, eventually causing your page to get slow or even unresponsive.

Since that post was written there's now a new way of attaching event handlers, called [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo), which makes it easier to [`stopListening`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening).

There's also now [`View.prototype.remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) method which will remove the view's element from the DOM and also call `stopListening` which will help in case you used `listenTo` to attach event handlers for the models.